# How do I get the value from a React Img component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I keep getting undefined from the console.log in 'handleClickVideo'. How can I get the value out of clicking on a video properly? I tried with a div also however div doesn't have a value property. I thought Img did though.

```
const Videos = ({ videos }) => {

const handleClickVideo = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
}

return (
    <>
        <h2 className="title is-5">Videos</h2>
        <div className="columns is-multiline">
        <VideoModal 
            videoOpen={videoOpen}
            setVideoClose={handleClickVideo}
        />
            {
                videos.map((video, key) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="column is-one-third">
                            <div className={styles.thumbnail}>
                                <Img src={`https://img.youtube.com/vi/${video.link}/0.jpg`} onClick={handleClickVideo} value={video.link}/>

                            </div>
                            <p className={styles.videoTitle}>Green Book Official Trailer</p>

                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>

    </>                
)
}
```

Comment: Are you using functional component ?

Comment: I'm using a functional component

Comment: Can you please add your VideoModal component code here ?

Comment: I think from VideoModal component you are not sending any event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `handleClickVideo` in `VideoModal` but `VideoModal` doesn't have any `value`, so it will be `undefined` in your callback

```
    <VideoModal 
        videoOpen={videoOpen}
        setVideoClose={handleClickVideo}
    />
```

You can make your callback function to accept a value:

```
const handleClickVideo = (video) => {
    console.log(video)
}
```

And then update your render function:

```
<VideoModal 
    videoOpen={videoOpen}
    setVideoClose={() => handleClickVideo(0)}
/>

<Img
    src={`https://img.youtube.com/vi/${video.link}/0.jpg`}
    onClick={()=>handleClickVideo(video.link)}
/>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm asking. How do I set a value in handleClickVideo?

Comment: I don't know what your `VideoModal` and `setVideoClose` are supposed to do

Comment: Thank you! I t was the onClick part I needed. Just didn't know how to pass that value and forgot I could throw it into onClick